# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to finetune and train a model for vulnerability detection and when I try to run the below code:

```
try:
    cw = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced',classes=[0,1],y=m1.label.tolist())
except:
    cw = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced',classes=[0,1],y=m1.target.tolist())
    
c_weights = torch.FloatTensor([cw[0], cw[1]])
```

It shows this error

```
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <cell line: 1>:2                                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'label'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <cell line: 1>:4                                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'target'
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: `m1` is a `list`, I'm guessing you expect it to be something else?

Answer (score 0):

as commented by @Guy

you are getting this error because:

`m1` is already a `list` and *'list' object has no attribute 'label'*

you maybe expecting m1 to be a numpy array or something.

Link to doc:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html